# R programming: delete rows above and below a specific number from a vector in R

Tags: r

I have a vector in R with zeroes,positive and negative numbers.I want to delete two values above and three values below every positive number and zero using for loops. How can I do it?

Comment: Vectors don't have rows...[Please share a reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269) example along with expected output

Comment: @Sotos It is quite obvious that nitsri is talking about vector elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a step by step solution:

```
# Generate a vector of random numbers between -10 and 3
v=round(runif(20)*13-10)

# Get positions of elements >= 0
to_delete=which(v>=0)

# Store position of elemets >=0, positions 1 or 2 before, and positions 1, 2, or 3
# after (i.e. the positions of elements we want to delete)
to_delete=c(to_delete, to_delete-1,to_delete-2,to_delete+1,to_delete+2,to_delete+3)

# Filter positions appearing multiple time and sort them
to_delete=sort(unique(to_delete))

# Keep only positions between 1 and length of initial vector
to_delete=to_delete[which(to_delete>0 & to_delete<=length(v))]

# Delete positions from the initial vector
output=v[-to_delete]

# Print outputs
print(v)
print(to_delete)
print(output)
```

Note that the output vector will be `numeric(0)` if there are no elements to keeh